# emmet - how to create 5 copies of two html tags

Tags: emmet

So I want to create this markup using emmet:

```
<h5></h5>
<p></p>
<h5></h5>
<p></p>
<h5></h5>
<p></p>
<h5></h5>
<p></p>
<h5></h5>
<p></p>
```

How do I achieve that?

`h5p*5` just gives me  tags

`h5>p*5` creates a single h5 with 5 paragraphs

`h5*5p*5` does nothing

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after reading the cheat sheet and playing around a bit:

```
(h5+p)*5
```